# Equipping magic find gear immediately before elite death

Tags: diablo-iii

What is stopping me from running through a rift, say, with my best gear, and then, right before I am about to kill an elite, quickly shifting to my magic find gear, killing the elite, and then switching right back to my best gear?  Is Diablo 3 smart enough to realize that you are 'gaming the system', so to speak?  I feel as if they don't nerf your MF when you do this, then the minimal time it takes to switch back and forth will not offset the increased legendary drop rate (as doing an entire rift with your MF gear might).

Certainly people have thought of this before.  Is it really that easy, or is there something in place to prevent this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Legendaries are already pretty easy to come by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing stopping you from swapping in magic-find gear right before a monster dies. I believe drops are determined at mob death, and there is no delay or cooldown on gear stats.

However, the consensus is that it's not worth it to do this. Magic find as a stat was nerfed with the expansion. It now provides only **30% of the listed bonus** for rare drops, and only **10% of the listed bonus** for legendary drops. Also, magic find does not appear as a stat on newly-dropping gear, only old gear.

So yes, you can do this, but it is going to be a lot of work (and bag space) for a small gain.

Sources:

- http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12089609261
- http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-misc-forums/theorycrafting-and-analysis/82815-magic-find-2-03-should-we-try-to-have-some

Comment: As well as the risk of dying due to wearing MF gear, which by todays standards would be incredibly outdated.